# How to get all elements of list in regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to print elements of list via regex this is my code:

```
myresult_tv = [ 'Extinct A Horizon Guide to Dinosaurs WEB h264-WEBTUBE', 'High Noon 2019 04 05 720p HDTV DD5 1 MPEG2-NTb', 'Wyatt Cenacs Problem Areas S02E01 1080p WEBRip x264-eSc', 'Bondi Vet S05E15 720p WEB x264-GIMINI', 'If Loving You Is Wrong S04E03 Randals Stage HDTV x264-CRiMSON', 'Wyatt Cenacs Problem Areas S02E01 WEBRip x264-eSc', 'Bondi Vet S05E15 1080p WEB x264-GIMINI']


li = []

for a in myresult_tv:
    w = re.match(".*\d ", a)
    c =w.group()
    li.append(c)

print(li)
```

and the result is :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "azazzazazaaz.py", line 31, in <module>
    c =w.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

***Repl Closed***
```

Comment: You need to check `if (w):` before accessing `.group()` on match object. What are you trying to extract from the string?

Comment: Why are you using regex if you're looking to get all elements from list?

Comment: @Austin no i want the get part of elements like `High Noon 2019 04 05` but the first element make code rise error and i need to skip those element like first element make error

Comment: @CryNetPlan, this should be the question; not a comment.

Comment: @Austin yes i think the error explain this problem sorry , do you have any idea for skip the wrong element?

Comment: Use the suggestion from @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi. That works.

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking if the regex matched the element of the list. You should be doing something like this:

```
match = re.search(pattern, string)
if match:
    process(match)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't understand what your expected output, I use the same regex as yours. Try use this code:

```
li = []
for a in myresult_tv:
    try:                             # I use try... except... in case the regex doesn't work at some list elements
        w = re.search("(.*\d )", a)  # I use search instead of match
        c = w.group()
        li.append(c)
    except:
        pass

print(li)
```